# HTML 5 Video in a responsive expandable banner

Tags: html, css, html5-video, css-transitions

I have created an expandable HTML5 banner that includes video in the expansion. I'd like for the video to autoplay when banner Expand button is clicked, and then stop playing with the Close button is clicked. Here is my code so far:

```
 <div class="ad_div2">
           <input type="button" value="EXPAND"    onclick="this.value=this.value=='EXPAND'?'CLOSE':'EXPAND'; fade(this);" class="bt"    style="background-color:#000000; color:#ffffff; ">
           <script>
            $(function() {  
$(".bt").click(function() {  
    $(".ad_div2").toggleClass("ad_change1");  
});  
});
           </script>   
  <video src="trailer_placeholder.mp4" controls style="width:70%; height:auto;            position:relative; margin-top:13%; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:5%;"></video>
       </div></div>
```

Here is some additional Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fade(btnElement) {
        if (btnElement.value === "EXPAND") {
            document.getElementById("myImg").className = "fade-out";

        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("myImg").className = "fade-in";

        }
    }
</script>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
    #myImg
     {
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
        opacity:0;
        padding-left:0;
        margin-top:0;
        width:85%;
        height:auto;
    }
    #myImg.fade-out
    {
        opacity:0;
    }
    #myImg.fade-in
    {
        opacity:1;
    }

 .ad_div2
  {
width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color: #000000;
z-index:0;
border:#000000 solid 2px;
background-image:url(i/avengers_logo.jpg);
background-position:center top;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition: width 2s ease, height 1s ease;  
 -moz-transition: width 2s ease, height 1s ease;  
 -o-transition: width 2s ease, height 1s ease;  
 -ms-transition: width 2s ease, height 1s ease;  
 transition: width 2s ease, height 1s ease;  
  }

   .ad_change1
    {
width:100%;
height:538px;
background-image:url(i/city_bg.png);
    }

   .content1
   {
width:80%;
float:left;
   }

  .content2
   {
width:20%;
float:right;
margin-left:0px;
margin-top:40px;
   }
```

It's getting close - the myImg tag was originally being used to fade in an image, perhaps something can be added in there to autoplay and stop video or will probably be on the button? ()

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have both an inline onclick and a jQuery click handler for the same input element? You could do all of this in a couple lines of code.

In either case, just call `$('video').get(0).play()` and `$('video').get(0).pause()` in your toggle.

Comment: Where would those calls go? in the onclick? Or where?

Comment: You'll have to forgive me I'm a designer really not a dev but I try! Thanks for any more direction!